# Geostatistics: disaggregating regional data to subregions

Tags: spatial, geostatistics, kriging

I have been reading a lot on geostatistics. I am still unsure this problem falls under the umbrella of geostatistics, or if it is statistically feasible at all.

I have the market share for a company at the national level, as well as the regional level. (The country is divided into 5 regions. This is for a small country, mind you.)

I would like to produce market share estimates for smaller subregions. For each of these subregions, I have all the same exogeneous variables that I have for the regions and for the nation (i.e. economic indicators, demographics, etc). I only lack the endogeneous variable: market share.

I wonder if it is possible to extrapolate the market share across these subregions, by first creating a model to estimate the causal relations: population indicators -> market share, and then possibly with the help of geostatistics (since these are physical stores) help the extrapolation... Can for instance kriging be used for this?

Comment: Also look up Conley standard errors and Conley's PhD thesis he builds a model suitable for spatial data. If you want to be extra-sophisticated you look for spatial Cournot behavior..

Comment: @Hirek why did you start your comment with "Also". Are you saying that kriging is an useful method for my estimation of market share at the subregion level?

Comment: Oh sorry I guess I was thinking with your text. I am not aware of kriging to be honest but in Econometrics Conley is the guy to look for https://ideas.repec.org/f/pco561.html look at his 2008 paper.

Comment: @Hirek, just to make it clear my reading of Conley, please confirm my interpretation of him ... Unlike most people from mathematics, I actually took a class in Econometrics, and it is my understanding they spend a good deal of time trying to work out heteroskedasticity problems. I understand that in many spatial situations you have problems arising from correlation/causality, because people move places. But I am not sure why I may have such problems in market share data. Oh wait, because the choice where stores are built is not random? (thank you for the link; I will sure read his writtings!)

Comment: What distinguishes Econometrics from Statistics is that behavioral issues are taken into account (if you take this to its logical conclusion, it's structural econometrics http://faculty.smu.edu/millimet/classes/eco7321/papers/macurdy.pdf) and yes, heterogeneity in agents which manifests itself often as heteroskedasticity. To answer your question, Conley considers a spatial ordering on cross-section data much like a time series is different from a cross-section because the data is ordered by time. Thereby, Conley generalizes this notion and finds efficiency (more predictive power) gains.